# ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs Can't import the named export 'drag' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: npm, react-scripts

I am trying `ForceGraph2D` using below dependencies, but getting below error. Please help me how to fix this?

./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs
Can't import the named export 'drag' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

[image]

Comment: Could you also share the code in which you try to import `drag`?

Comment: Please see my code line, here i am uisng enableNodeDrag <ForceGraph2D enableNodeDrag={true} />

Comment: Seems to be a javascript (or typescript?) config mismatch between the package and your project. It would be possible to help you if you provide your entire project in a sandbox.